# Como pegar o valor de um input e usar em outro componente em react?

Tags: javascript, react

```
import './App.css'
import './Conveter'
import converter from './Conveter'

function App() {
  return (
    <body>
      <header>
        <h1>Conversor De Moedas</h1>
      </header>
      <div id="container">
        <h2>USD Para BRA </h2>
        <input
          type="number"
          min="0.00"
          id="valor"
          name="valor"
        />

        <button onClick={converter}>Converter</button>
        <p>Valor convertido</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  )
}

export default App
```

Alguem poderia me explicar como faço para pegar o valor que será digitado nesse input em outro componente do meu projeto ?

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns formas, uma delas é passar via `props` e com reação de mudança desse valor no componente ***Pai*** fazer com que o outro componente receba essa nova mudança, um exemplo bem básico:

```js
function Container(props){
  return (
    <div>Filho: {props.name}</div>
  )
}
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  function handleOnChange(e){    
    setName(e.target.value);
  }  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input 
          type="text"
          name="name"        
          id="name"
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
      </div>
      <Container name={name || "nenhuma valor"} />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Esse exemplo é o mais simples, outro exemplo seria com um contexto de informações onde um componente compartilhe todo os valores que nele existe para os componentes que estão como seu filho, é uma maneira muito utilizado na elaboração de **login** ou compartilhamento de informações globais, **exemplo**:

```js
const IndexContext = React.createContext();
function IndexContextProvider(props) {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <IndexContext.Provider value={{name, setName}}>
      {props.children}
    </IndexContext.Provider>
  );
}
function useName() {
  const ctx = React.useContext(IndexContext);
  const {name, setName} = ctx;
  return {name, setName};
}
function Container(){
  const {name} = useName()
  return (
    <div>Filho: {name || "nenhum valor" }</div>
  )
}
function App() {
  const {name, setName} = useName();
  function handleOnChange(e) {
    setName(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div>
        <input 
          type="text"
          name="name"        
          id="name"
          value={name}
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
        <Container />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <IndexContextProvider><App/></IndexContextProvider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Nesse segundo exemplo, observe que a variável name e seu método para alteração estão em um componente muito acima (componente pai) e é nele que todas os outros componentes consegue resgatar o seu valor atualizado. Pra facilitar é utilizado nesse exemplo uma função com a nomenclatura Hooks de nome `useName` que é mais fácil transportar as informações entre componente e um padrão utilizada pela comunidade.

Além dessas duas maneiras existe pacotes que tem também o caracter de compartilhar informações de maneira global, como por exemplo [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/).

***Referencias:***

- [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)
- [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- [Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)